# Rest-Assured - json body assertion for set of values in list regardless of position

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using rest-assured to test a rest api. I have a json response that returns an array of objects. I want verify that it contains objects with specific test of values. Check the following example:

Example JSON:

```
{
    "contents" : [
         {  
              "field1" : "value1",
              "field2" : "value2"
         },
         {  
              "field1" : "value3",
              "field2" : "value4"
         }
    ]
}
```

How do I write the body assertion so that I can check that regardless of the position I have one entry with:

value1 & value2  in each respective field
and another entry with value3 & value4.

```
...get ("/myEndpoint" )
.then()
.body ( "contents.?????", contains...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depend on what you mean by "regardless of position".

If you mean regardless of position in `contents` but it's important that `field1` is specified before `field2` you can do like this:

```
when().
        get("/myEndpoint").
then().
        root("contents.any { it == ['field1':'%s', 'field2':'%s'] }").
        body(withArgs("value1", "value2"), is(true)).
        body(withArgs("value3", "value4"), is(true));
```

If you don't care if `field1` is specified before `field2` you can do like this:

```
when().
        get("/myEndpoint").
then().
        root("contents").
        body("", hasItems(hasEntry("field2", "value2"), hasEntry("field1", "value1")),
             "", hasItems(hasEntry("field1", "value3"), hasEntry("field2", "value4")));
```

You can read up on "root paths" [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#root-path).